# How to get the last emitted value through behaviorsubject in another component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

By using behaviorsubject I am able to get the last emitted value in same component, but after navigating to another component I get the default value (NOT the last emitted value)

I used BehaviorSubject to update a value in one component and tried to get the updated value in another component.

First Component

```
bs = new BehaviorSubject<string>('default value');
currentMessage = this.bs.asObservable();
submit(){
   this.bs.next('updated value');
   this.bs.subscribe(message=> console.log(message));
   this.router.navigate(['../new-view']);
  }
```

another component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.firstComponent.currentMessage.subscribe(message=> 
console.log(message));
  }
```

in new view/another component I get the default value, however I was expecting updated value.

I fisrt component I get the updated value.

Could you please help!

Comment: You should use a `service` to share data between components if the components are not in parent-child relationship. Have a look at [this tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/). You may find it useful.

Comment: I am using first component as a service as to use included it to providers in app.module.ts

Comment: when you cast `BehaviorSubject` to Observable via `asObservable`, it inherits behavior of returning last value on subscription.

Comment: @nircraft using this.firstComponent.bs.subscribe(message=> 
console.log(message)); also yields the same result.

Comment: I think that using a component as a service is an anti-pattern in Angular. And besides that Angular components are not singleton. This means, when you navigate to another component, the previous component will be destroyed. So again I suggest you to use a proper Angular service to share data.

Comment: @HarunYılmaz got it. Thank you ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `bs = new BehaviorSubject<string>('default value');` in a service and injecting the service to needed components for sharing data.

The reason you are not getting the **new value in the second component** is because The previous component's scope is destroyed when you navigate away from it and happen to load the second component which got the value from the `BehaviorSubject` initiation time. At the time your `BehaviorSubject` is initialized, all it's subscribers get the first value.

If you use a service to do that, all your components can get the updated value.